# Where should I inject Bearer tokens into $http in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth, bearer-token

After the user's credential has been accepted I fetch the Bearer token [1] and update the default headers:

```
     $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer #{data.access_token}"
```

This is done at the end of the $scope.signIn() method. Will the tokens be persistent throughout the entire session or should I use an other technic?

[1] https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Client-Credentials-flow

```
app.run run = ($http, session) ->
    token = session.get('token')
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
```

Comment: Yes it would be, as long as you do not refresh the page. If the token has to be persisted on refresh you need to store it browser local storage.

Comment: The token needs to be persistent. How can I make sure $http uses that token if I store it in a Service?  Shall I put it in app.run? See example code in the original post. :)

Comment: Yeah, app.run is executed every time I refresh the page. I'll put it there.

Answer (score 13):

A great way to solve this problem is to create an authInterceptor factory responsible for adding the header to all $http requests:

```
angular.module("your-app").factory('authInterceptor', [
  "$q", "$window", "$location", "session", function($q, $window, $location, session) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + session.get('token'); // add your token from your service or whatever
        return config;
      },
      response: function(response) {
        return response || $q.when(response);
      },
      responseError: function(rejection) {
        // your error handler
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Then in your app.run:

```
// send auth token with requests
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

Now all requests made with $http (or $resource for that matter) will send along the authorization header.

Doing it this way instead of changing $http.defaults means you get way more control over the request and response, plus you can use a custom error handler too or use whatever logic you want to determine whether the auth token should be sent or not.