# How to download a file using Angular with Bearer token

Tags: angularjs, passport.js, adal, azure-active-directory

we have secured our application using Azure AD + OpenID connect. The client application is developed in Angular and we are using 'angular-adal' library for integrating with azure ad. So whenever client makes api call to the server, it automatically includes bearer token in the request header. ( on the server we have 'passport-azure-ad' node library which validates the token)

We have download file functionality which is currently implemented as blow

**Controller**

```
    $scope.getURL = function (reportId) {
                return '/api/reports/download/' + reportId;
    };
```

**HTML**

```
     <form method="get" action="{{getURL(row.id)}}">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Download Results</button>
     </form>
```

However it does not include the bearer token in the request when i click on download button, so server returns not authorized error. How do i included token in the request? whats the best way?

**UPDATE1**
As per the recommendation by [Angular ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) library, we can secure the route by setting 'requiredADLogin' property to true in  $routeProvider. Like below

```
    $routeProvider.
         when("/todoList", {
              controller: "todoListController",
              templateUrl: "/App/Views/todoList.html",
              requireADLogin: true
      });
```

I am using $stateProvider. I have set the states for all other html page routes with 'requiredADLogin', and that works fine. How do i set $stateProvider for API route. My Download url is

```
'/api/reports/download/'+reportID
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009634/where-should-i-inject-bearer-tokens-into-http-in-angularjs  Author suggests writing an interceptor to inject auth tokens into `$http` requests.

Comment: @user3862378 see update1

Comment: How did you fix your problem ? I am encountering pretty much the same issue. Downlad a file with ADAL.js using ADFS authentication in my Web API. Hell the url is basically the same as well ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Azure AD but I guess you need to set the Authentication token somehow like this in the header:

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: '/api/reports/download/' + reportId,
 headers: {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
 }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```